# Emulator: WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan

Tags: android, android-emulator, vulkan, unreal-engine5

I'm trying to run an application on Android emulator with unreal engine.
However, the unreal supports only opens 3.2, and the emulator supports only 3.1.
So I'm going to run the application with the vulkan.
But my Android emulator doesn't seem to support vulkan.
Emulator: WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
There was a warning like this.
May I know how to update it?

I searched a lot on the Internet, but I couldn't find the answer...
I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably the Android Emulator version your using. [Vulkan support](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#29.0.6-vulkan) started with Android Q Beta 3 or higher for Vulkan 1.1 and Android Q Beta 2 for Vulkan 1.0 (API 29). You can [create](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#createavd) a new emulator with Android API 30 or higher that it should work or manually enable the feature.

To enable Vulkan support, you must add the following feature flags to your `~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini` file (create the file if it doesn’t exist):

```
Vulkan = on
GLDirectMem = on`
```

> Note: Snapshots can’t currently be used while Vulkan is enabled. If
> you enable Vulkan support, the current quickboot snapshot is
> invalidated.

Answer (score -3):

I faced the same issue with this message

```
INFO | Android emulator version 32.1.14.0 (build_id 10330179) (CL:N/A) INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-R\google_apis_playstore\x86\ WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. INFO | IPv4 server found: 122.232.152.55
```

Try this, run `cmd` **as administator** then type this

```
RD \S C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Temp
```